# How to maintain the background color while adding an image in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX program to play chess. Currently, I am using the JavaFX Rectangle class and setting them up with dark and light colors. However, when I go to add the image, it clears the entire background even though I intentionally found images with clear backgrounds. Currently the code I am using to put the image on the Rectangles is:

```
rectangleArray[i][row].setFill(new ImagePattern(image));
```

where image is the image I want in this particular case. Do I need to use different JavaFX classes in order to be able to do this? Or am I simply using the wrong methods?

Comment: Use a `StackPane`. <- Just a guess. I would have to see more to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set a single `fill` on a `Rectangle`. Setting the `fill` to a different value replaces the old fill instead of "adding" to it.

You should use a pane with a background instead and add a `ImageView` to it, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final double size = 50;

    ImageView pawn = new ImageView("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Chess_tile_pd.png");
    pawn.setFitWidth(size);
    pawn.setFitHeight(size);

    final Background grey = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GRAY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
    final Background white = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints(size);
    RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        grid.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
        grid.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            StackPane field = new StackPane();
            field.setBackground(((i + j) & 1) == 0 ? white : grey);
            grid.add(field, i, j);
            field.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
                if (pawn.getParent() != field) {
                    field.getChildren().add(pawn); // move pawn to this field on click
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ((Pane) grid.getChildren().get(0)).getChildren().add(pawn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```